# How can i provide a search screen that will show participant information?

Tags: civievent, search-builder

I am on Joomla and civiCRM 4.7 and I want to have a search screen available through a Joomla menu item for participant information. I'd like my staff to be able to search for registration items for our conference. For example, I'd like them to search for all attendees who have a special meal or signed up for a workshop?

Comment: Along the lines of Find Participants under the Search menu item?

Comment: No, I want to create a profile on the Joomla main menu so my staff can search for conference participants using criteria such as workshops or meal choices without logging into the back end. Can I do this?